# Analogues of proper-smooth basechange for etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

If we are given a map of schemes $f:X\to S$ that is smooth and proper the proper-smooth basechange Theorem will say that the derived functors the sheaf $R^if_*\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ is lcc. I was wondering if there are other situations in which we can also conclude that the these sheaves are "local systems". I am particularly interested in the situation in which $S=Spec(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, the map $f:X\to S$ is only assumed smooth and you want to want to conclude $H_c^i(X_{\over{\mathbb{F}}_p},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)=H_c^i(X_{\over{\mathbb{Q}}_p},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$. What would we have to assume on the compactification? Any reference to a classically know case would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Ian. Note that $H^i_c(X_\eta,\mathbb{Q}_\ell)=H^i(\ov{X_\eta},j_!\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ and that this latter sheaf is by proper base change $H^i(\ov{X_s},R\Psi j_!\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ (where $R\Psi$ are nearby cycles). So, what you're essentially afteter is conditions when the adjunction morphism relating the compositions $j_!$ and $R\Psi$ in both orders is an isomorphis. This is very senstive not only to how good the compactification is, but the actual sheaf in question (e.g. it can be true for some sheaves and not others). For an example of where this does hold you can see

Comment: Lemma 5.10 of this: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~kwlan/articles/nearby-aut.pdf. Hopefully that gives you a good place to start. This paper shows that the result yoru after is true, in some sense, for Shimura varieties and certain automorphic sheaves on them.